# Variable desde <a href> a php

Tags: variables, get, href

Tengo una duda muy concreta
Qué debo poner después de txtCodigo= para que el número de después del = se corresponda al código correcto en cada momento.

````
if (isset($_GET['Codigo'])) {
    $Codigo = $_GET['Codigo'];
}

?>
<p class="MSGInfor">Se ha cambiado el estado correctamente</p>

<?php
echo "<p class='link'><a href='LibConsultarCodigo.php?txtCodigo=$Codigo'>Volver a la consulta del libro</a></p>";
?> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Tu código generalmente está funcionando, pero tienes que:

- preparar el valor para utilizar en URL (`urlencode`; por exemplo, cambia espacio en blanco a `%20`)
- preparar el valor para imprimir en la pagina HTML (`htmlspecialchars`; por exemplo, cambia `<` a `&lt;`)

```
<?php
$CodigoEncoded = htmlspecialchars(urlencode($Codigo));
echo "<p class='link'><a href='LibConsultarCodigo.php?txtCodigo=$CodigoEncoded'>Volver a la consulta del libro</a></p>";
?>
```

Comment: Vale he probado esto, pero ahora cuando presiono en 'Volver a la consulta del libro' me dice que no existe ningún libro con el código: txtCodigo

Answer (score 0):

El error es que estás buscando el dato en una clave incorrecta al usar `$_GET['Codigo']`, cuando deberías buscar el dato en `$_GET['txtCodigo']`.

Es preciso entender que cuando mandas información en la URL (o por medio de un formulario), lo que ocurre es que los datos son serializados en un array (`$_GET` no es otra cosa que un array). En ese array, la clave es el dato de la izquierda: `txtCodigo` y el valor es el dato que está después de `=`. (Cuando usas un formulario, la clave es lo que haya escrito en la etiqueta `name` y el valor es lo que haya escrito en el `value` de cada elemento y no se serializan los elementos que no tengan datos en el `value`).

Por tanto, en esta URL:

```
LibConsultarCodigo.php?txtCodigo=$Codigo
```

`$_GET` será un array así (esto es para entender la estructura de GET, no es parte del código):

```
 txtCodigo => $Codigo
```

Donde `$Codigo` será el valor que se haya pasado.

### Lo que tienes que corregir

Por lo dicho anteriormente, para encontrar el dato tienes que hacer esto:

```
if (isset($_GET['txtCodigo'])) {
    $Codigo = $_GET['txtCodigo'];
}
```

Nótese que verificamos `txtCodigo`, no `Codigo`.

Supongamos algo así:

```
LibConsultarCodigo.php?txtCodigo=7&txtNombre=Pedro
```

En este caso, `$_GET` será un array con dos claves y dos valores:

```
 txtCodigo => 7    
 txtNombre => Pedro
```

Y para obtener los datos, tienes que pedirlos por el nombre de las claves respectivas:

```
$_GET['txtCodigo']
$_GET['txtNombre']
```

En pocas palabras, **`$_GET`  es un array**, no hay más misterio. Eso lo puedes comprobar fácilmente haciendo algo como `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: Okay entiendo, pero ahora me da error de sintaxis con: textCodigo => $Codigo. ¿Dónde debo escribirlo?

Comment: @MarcTobella eso no es parte del código, sino para explicar la estructura del GET, lo que tienes que corregir es esto: `if (isset($_GET['txtCodigo'])) {
    $Codigo = $_GET['txtCodigo'];
}` Creo que está explicado con claridad en la respuesta, si hay alguna duda me lo dices en otro comentario.

Comment: Disculpa, lo rectifiqué despúes, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema. No se que debo poner después de LibConsultarCodigo.php?txtCodigo=   para que me devuelva el código correspondiente en cada caso